# getting invalid Mapping Exception in hibernate

Tags: hibernate

I have developed an application in hibernate below are the pojo's but I am getting mapping exception please advise

Here is my person pojo..

```
 package mypack;

public class Person
{
     private int personId;
     private String name;
     private Address address;
    public Person() 
    {
        super();
    }
    public Person(String name, Address address) 
    {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
    }
    public int getPersonId() {
        return personId;
    }
    public void setPersonId(int personId) {
        this.personId = personId;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public Address getAddress() {
        return address;
    }
    public void setAddress(Address address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
    }
```

and the address pojo is

```
    package mypack;

public class Address 
{
     private int id;
     private String city,state;

    public Address()
    {
        super();

    }

    public Address(String city, String state)
    {
        super();
        this.city = city;
        this.state = state;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }
    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }
    public String getState() {
        return state;
    }
    public void setState(String state) {
        this.state = state;
    }
     }
```

and the corresponding hbm mapping file is pkfk.hbm.xml ..

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
          "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
          "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<!-- Generated by MyEclipse Hibernate Tools.                   -->
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="mypack.Person">
<id name="personId" type="int">
<generator class="increment"/>
</id>
<property name="name"/>
<many-to-one name="address" class="mypack.Address" column="addressId" unique="true" cascade="all"/>
</class>


<class name="mypack.Address">
<id name="id" column="addressId" type="int">
<generator class="increment"/>
</id>
<property name="city"/>
<property name="state"/>
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

and my main program file is ...

```
package mypack;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class TestProgram 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
      try
      {
       SessionFactory sesfac=new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
       Session ses=sesfac.openSession();
       Person p=new Person("Anupam",new Address("Noida","U.P"));
       Person p1=new Person("Rekha Singh",new Address("Kanpur","U.P"));
       System.out.println("Persisting Object...");
       Transaction tx=ses.beginTransaction();
       ses.save(p);
       ses.save(p1);
       tx.commit();
       System.out.println("Successfully Persisted.");
       ses.close();
      }
      catch(Exception e)
      {
          System.out.println(e);
      }
    }
}
```

upon excuting the main file I am getting the following error..

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.hibernate.cfg.Environment).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Could not parse mapping document from resource samePK.hbm.xml
```

Please advise what is wrong and how to correct it this invalid Mapping Exception

Comment: Post the complete stack trace of the exception.

Answer (score 0):

You named your file `pkfk.hbm.xml`, and Hibernate tries reading `samePK.hbm.xml`. Your main config file must be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

if anyone get stuck in Invalid Mapping Exception when using spring and hibernate integration pls check carefully spelling mistake in springbean.xml file (whatever u given ) then check carefully hibernate.hbm.xml file bcs as my opinion most of time we faced problem like only cause of spelling mistake.
1)variable name correct corresponding to hbm file;
2)all getter/setter are there or not.
3)when u load springbean.xml file by using *ClassPathXmlApplicationContext* passing as in constructor then check its spelling name.
4)id tag must be.its type either String or int ,long any one k

This is my experience that i share with u. I hope this is useful for all.